# Automapper - ignore properties when nested as a child

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two simple DTO defined that I'm passing to automapper v10.0.0

```cs
class RequestDTO {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   // other properties
   public IEnumerable<AssetDTO> Assets { get; set; }
}

class AssetDTO {
   public int RequestId { get; set; }
   // other properties
}
```

When I map an asset, it should show the `RequestId`. That's working fine. However, when I map a `RequestDTO`, there's no reason for each asset to include the `RequestId` as the `Id` is already included via the `RequestDTO`.

Is there a simple way to ignore the `RequestId` when it's being mapped as a result of the parent request being mapped?

So if I'm just mapping an asset, I want

```json
{
  "RequestId": 12,
  "OtherProperty": ""
}
```

but if I'm mapping a request, I want:

```json
{
  "Id": 12,
  "Assets": [
    {
      "OtherProperty", ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is nothing about mapping, but about the shape of the data object. `AssetDTO` is a class and it *has* the `RequestId` property defined. So, you cannot just expect to create an `AssetDTO` object and *not have* the `RequestId` property in it.

Even if you try to ignore it in the mapping process, you will end up having `RequestId` with a value of 0 (the default value for `int` type).

The main purpose of DTOs is to create data objects in different shapes as required, and it's fairly common to create a multitude of DTOs to map from a single Model type. Hence a solution to your problem would be using two different DTOs for mapping an `Asset` type in two different scenarios -

```cs
class ChildAssetDTO
{
    // other properties    // no RequestId in this class
}

class AssetDTO : ChildAssetDTO
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }    // only the RequestId in this class
}

class RequestDTO
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   // other properties
   public IEnumerable<ChildAssetDTO> Assets { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use `AssetDTO` to map an `Asset` type, and `AssetChildDTO` to map a `Request` type.